# Hibernate Exception : java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'T2'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

In my Spring-Hibernate Application, i have 4 bean classes like UserVO,BookVO,AttandanceVO and Timetable.

and my AttendanceVO bean class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID")
private BookVO book;
 //Setters and getters.
```

and my BookVO bean class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private UserVO user;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Time_ID")
private TimeTable timetable;

//Setters and getters
```

In my Hibernate class i'm writing query ..

```
 @Transactional
public List<AttendanceVO> findAttendanceList(UserVO user){
    TypedQuery<AttendanceVO> query = entityManager.createQuery("select av from AttendanceVO av inner join av.book bb  where bb.user=:user",
            AttendanceVO.class);
    query.setParameter("user", user);
    return query.getResultList();
 }
```

But i'm get Exception like..

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/EClass] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.sits.ec.valueObjects.BookVO#A2]] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'T2'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
 ..............
```

Actually T2 is Timetable Id, why T2 coming hear i'm not include timetable in my query ..

Is their any mapping needed?

```
Edit 1:


 @Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class BookVO{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private UserVO user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TIMETABLE_ID")
    private TimetableVO timetable;
//Setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Share the other domain classes and the basic table ctructure...

Comment: not related to the question, but, you should only use `@Transactional` when you are changing data, no need to have the annotation when u are only seleting

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is some null value in DB. when hibernate tried to map with class integer field, it throwing this exception. This is what happened to me. I used below in select caluse to handle null value explicitly

```
   ISNULL("column having null value", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can map UserVO to DB primitive types , you should check the datatype of USER_ID column , and map that type to your code.
try to exact map types from hibernate to your db.